# Start AutoCAD without NETLOAD command

Tags: c#, dll, command, autocad-plugin

I'm currently doing a small university project on C#, so in one part of my program I need to start AutoCAD commands without using "NETLOAD" key word and without selection of appropriate the dll-file for it. Is there any possible implemetion? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AutoLoader.  Here's an example to get you started:

https://spiderinnet1.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/autoloader-101-1-a-simple-working-sample.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've already done it with a registry and it works!

Comment: Glad you got it working with the registry option.  One thing to note: if you don't have local admin rights on a computer you're trying to install to, the registry option may not work.  Using the autoloader option and placing the files in c:\ProgramData\ will always work.